# Coding dichotomous variables in multiple linear regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, categorical-encoding

Say I want to predict continuous Y with continuous X and dichotomous D1 and D2 with a multiple linear regression model. The hypothesis is that X negatively predicts Y on one level of D1 (the control level), and the negative predictive power should reduce on the other level of D1 (the treatment level). These effects should not differ between the two levels of D2 (i.e., D2 does not interact with X or D1).

If D1 and D2 are dummy coded and with the control level coded as 0, one cannot interpret the coefficient of X as its simple effect on Y on the control level of D1, because there is also D2. If D1 and D2 are sum coded, then one cannot read directly from the model output whether X significantly and negatively predicts Y on the control level of D1.

The question: how should one code D1 and D2 to properly test the hypotheses? If testing them requires building multiple models, what models would make sense, and in what order should one build them?

Thank you very much.